# detecting vulnerabilities in web applications and desktop applications

Tags: java, javascript, html, c, security

Sorry, this is not a question about a specific programming language, but i need opinion on this. Please don't vote for close.

where do I learn about detecting vulnerabilities from the scratch?

I know HTML, CSS, JS, Java, and C.

So, where do I learn about detecting vulnerabilities in applications written in these prog. languages?

I heard of contests where "hackers" detect vulnerabilities in web browsers in mere seconds. I know experience is the main key here! but what other factors I can grow in myself to be one like this?

PS: Don't see "google", I`m looking for recommendation!

Comment: You can start here: www.owasp.org

Answer (score 2):

A good start is the OWASP top 10 list:

[Category: OWASP Top Ten Project](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project)

The huge majority of any web security vulnerabilities will fall into these categories.

Comment: I was halfway through typing what was almost already on that list. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

For starters CSS, HTML and JS don't really contributed to the insecurity of your application.   There is [DOM Based XSS](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS),  but that is very uncommon.  By contrast many vulnerabilities are found in Java and C each year.

There are 2 major methodologies for finding vulnerabilities in code.   There is static code analysis using tools like grep or [Rats](https://www.fortify.com/ssa-elements/threat-intelligence/rats.html) or more advanced tools like the ones provided by Fortify and Coverity.

The other method is by fuzzing application.  For looking for problems like buffer overflows in non-web applications [Peach](http://peachfuzzer.com/) is an excellent testing platform.   For testing web applications for common vulnerabilities like XSS and SQL Injection then you should use tools like Wapiti(open source) or [Sitewatch](https://sitewat.ch/) (free service).